# gerrit admin does not have "Access Database" capability

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to access database of my gerrit server with the following command(I am the `admin` and my username is `newbie`) -

`ssh -p 29418 localhost gerrit gsql`

I get the following error :-

```
fatal: newbie does not have "Access Database" capability.
```

How to give administrators database access in gerrit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the `gsql` documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-gsql.html#_access):

> Caller must have been granted the [Access Database](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#capability_accessDatabase) global capability.

Global capabilities are [configured in the `project.config` file](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html#capability-section), e.g.

```
[capability]
       accessDatabase = group Administrators
```

Comment: For more details, please also see ["Gerrit Access Database Capability?"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/x00M_NtWekA).  You can either make the change via WebUI or by cloning and modifying the All-Projects repo